# Exchange server is not relaying Coldfusion emails to external addresses

Tags: email, coldfusion, exchange-server

I have a Coldfusion page (CF10) that creates a report and sends it via cfmail to a list of recipients. The ones in our internal domain are receiving, but the external addresses are not.

I found a couple threads where people were having the exact same problem, and the solution was to add the CF server's IP address to the Exchange server. So our IT guys did just that - they added the IP addresses of all of our production servers to the receive connector on the Exchange server. However, the mails are still not being relayed, and I'm continuing to get the same message in the mail log:
javax.mail.SendFailedException: Invalid Addresses;   nested exception is:   com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPAddressFailedException: 550 5.7.1 Unable to relay

I'm not familiar with everything that needs to happen to make the Exchange Server relay email to external addresses. Adding the IP addresses to the receive connector obviously isn't enough. Are there other steps that need to be performed?

Comment: The "IT guys" need to set up a relay for you to send the email. Just as the error says. They should know how to do this. It's more then just adding an IP in some cases. Not really a SO question otherwise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution was simple - we originally specified the mail server in the cfadmin mail settings, but included no username/password. That worked fine, until we wanted to start sending cfmails to addresses outside of our own domain. So IT created a dedicated "Noreply" account for this purpose, and I entered the username/password in the cfadmin mail settings.

Answer (score 0):

Coordinate with your IT guys.  Write a ColdFusion page that they can run that sends mail to an external address they can access.  Then tell them to do what they have to do to receive mail at that address.